# How to connect spring-boot with mariadb docker container with non 'root' user?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I can successfully connect to a `mariadb` `docker` container with user `root` as follows:

`application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://my_db:3306/dev
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=rootpw
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    container_name: my_app
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: my_db
    image: mariadb:10
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpw
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=rootpw
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dev
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db:
```

Problem: as soon is I change the user from `root` to `asd`:

`application.properties`: `spring.datasource.username=asd`

`docker-compose.yml`: `MYSQL_USER=asd`

Result:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: (conn=3)
> Access denied for user 'asd'@'XXXX.XX.X.X' (using password: YES)

The problem here seems to be that the `MYSQL_USER` is cached in the volume.

Question: how can I enfore recreation of the default `MYSQL_USER` user on the volume?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I could cleanup the volume with `docker-compose down -v`, and then build again. I was not aware the mariadb container obviously caches the initially created `MYSQL_USER`.